# sql time between two times

Tags: sql-server

I have a table EmployeeShifts where I am inserting employee shifts.
 Before inserting/updating a record I want to know whether user has any shift or not (for the given datime range).

I have tried below code but its not working.

```
declare @Datefrom date
declare @Dateto date
declare @Timefrom nvarchar(200)
declare @Timeto nvarchar(200)

    set @Datefrom ='2017-01-12'
    set @Dateto ='2017-01-30'
    set @Timefrom='03:00 pm'
    set @Timeto='11:30 pm'    

 if exists(select CAST(timefrom as time), CAST(timeto as time),* from EmployeeShifts where [Uid]=11 and Active=1 and        

        ((Datefrom between @Datefrom and @Dateto and 
        ((CAST(timefrom As Time) between CAST(@Timefrom As Time) and  CAST(@Timeto As Time)) or (CAST(timeto As Time) between CAST(@Timefrom As Time) and  CAST(@Timeto As Time))))
        or
         (Dateto between @Datefrom and @Dateto and 
        ((CAST(timefrom As Time) between CAST(@Timefrom As Time) and  CAST(@Timeto As Time)) or (CAST(timeto As Time) between CAST(@Timefrom As Time) and  CAST(@Timeto As Time)))
         )))
          begin
                  print 'User is already in a shift.'                    
         end
```

Should I need to concatenate date and time to get a datetime field?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Ok thanks @jarlh..

Comment: What doesn't work? You have set  twice `TimeTo` and forgot `TimeFrom`

Comment: If you're wanting to store a date and a time, why not use a type *designed* for holding such values - `datetime2`? You're creating problems for yourself by splitting the data and storing some of it in the wrong data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a design issue with your table that is causing you to do more work than you need to. If you have date and time values in separate columns you are always going to have to do extra work to execute queries like this. You should store shift start times and end times as `datetime` values. Look at this sample and see how much simpler you could make your life:

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeShifts
    (
      EmployeeId INT ,
      StartTime DATETIME ,
      EndTime DATETIME
    );

INSERT  INTO #EmployeeShifts
        ( EmployeeId, StartTime, EndTime )
VALUES  ( 1, '20170105 09:00:00', '20170105 17:00:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170106 09:00:00', '20170106 17:00:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170107 09:00:00', '20170107 17:00:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170105 09:00:00', '20170105 17:00:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170108 09:00:00', '20170108 17:00:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170109 09:00:00', '20170109 17:00:00' );

DECLARE @from DATETIME = '20170106 07:00:00' ,
        @to DATETIME = '20170108 18:00:00';

SELECT  *
FROM    #EmployeeShifts
WHERE   StartTime BETWEEN @from AND @to
        AND EndTime BETWEEN @from AND @to;

DROP TABLE #EmployeeShifts;
```